# ldap query for blank attribute value?

Tags: ldap

How does one query an ldap attribute for a blank value?  The equivalent of `str1==null` in programming?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
(&(objectCategory=computer)(whenCreated>=20160101000000.0Z)(description=))
(&(objectCategory=computer)(whenCreated>=20160101000000.0Z)(description=''))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to negate matching the wildcard `*` (any value) :

```
(&(objectCategory=computer)(whenCreated>=20160101000000.0Z)(!description=*))
```

From Microsoft's [LDAP Query Basics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx):

> The ! operator in conjunction with the wildcard operator will look for objects where that attribute is not set to anything.